# build-impl.xml:1025: The module has not been deployed. (Wicket)

Tags: java, netbeans, web

I have been working on a Java web application using *wicket* framework on *Netbeans 7.2* and out of a sudden I encountered this problem. I tried cleaning the `build-impl.xml` then restarting the IDE and I should say I have fairly low knowledge on this. Can someone please tell me why it is giving an error and how I can fix that?

The lines 1024, 1025 and 1026 are :

```
<target if="netbeans.home" name="-run-deploy-nb">
   <nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
</target>
```

The error message says :

```
nbproject/build-impl.xml:1025: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 4 seconds)
```

Comment: It seems that something happened on application server side. Which application server do you use? What does server's log say?

Comment: I recieved a similar error after I allowed netbeans to update automatically.  I was not able to resolve it quickly, so I just jumped to Netbeans7.3beta which is working fine (aside from the wicket plugin for 7.2).  I should probably submit a bug report...

Comment: I use Apache Tomcat, but since I fixed the problem, I can't remember what server's log said

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution by myself, I cloned the project and changed the project's directory name back to original, that worked fine for me. But it seems to have a better and proper solution, though.

Answer (score 1):

/* START BY RESTARTING YOUR GLASSFISH SERVER */

1-add DBMS(ex:oracle,MySQL,MsSQL..) jdbc connector jar to domain
    "glassfish directory/domain/{yourDomain}/lib"

2-add connection pool in glassfish server "JDBC-->ConnectionPool"

3-add your JNDI "JDBC-->jdbc ressource"

4-Test connection

5-add additional properties

IF YOU HAVE NO PASSWORD ON YOUR DATABASE ACCOUNT YOU CAN EASILY

6- glassfish/config/domain.xml change password value to "" in your jdbc-connection-pool

Answer (score -1):

may its so late but the response useful for others so : Sometimes, when you don't specify a server or servlet container at the creation of the project, NetBeans fails to create a context.xml file.

```
In your project under Web Pages, create a folder called META-INF.
```

Do this by right mouse button clicking on Web pages, and select:

New->Other->Other->File Folder

Name the folder META-INF. Case is important, even on Windows.

```
Create a file called context.xml in the META-INF folder.
```

Do this by right mouse button clicking on the new META-INF folder, and select:

New->Other->XML->XML Document

Name it context (NetBeans adds the .xml) Select Well-formed Document Press Finish

```
Edit the new document (context.xml), and add the following:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/app-name"/>
```

Replace app-name with the name of your application.

Now your in-place deployment should work. If not, make sure that the file can be read by everyone.

The context.xml file is specific to Tomcat. For more information about that file, see the Tomcat documentation at tomcat.apache.org.