# netbeans: build-impl.xml:1025: The module has not been deployed (error)

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, glassfish

I am trying to build and run a java web application in netbeans. While building it was fine, but while trying to run, it is showing a message

```
 compile:
compile-jsps:
Starting GlassFish Server
GlassFish Server is running.
In-place deployment at /home/..../Desktop/bookstore/web/n1/build/web
GlassFish Server, deploy, null, false
/home/..../Desktop/bookstore/web/n1/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1025: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 12 seconds)
```

Following is the code is there the specified location

```
1024: <target if="netbeans.home" name="-run-deploy-nb">
1025:   <nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
1026: </target>
```

I tried the sollution given in [build-impl.xml:1031: The module has not been deployed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16400810/build-impl-xml1031-the-module-has-not-been-deployed) but no use. It is still showing that massage and not able to run myapplication. How to overcome this error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13331926/4290096

Comment: is your issue same ?

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴠʏ . ya but it was not working. so i tried with tomact server again got similar error posted in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35793056/netbeans-build-impl-xml1032-the-module-has-not-been-deployed-error