# netbeans - build-impl.xml:1032: The module has not been deployed (error)

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, tomcat7

I am trying to build and run a java web application in netbeans. While building it was fine, but while trying to run, it is showing a message

```
 deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
Copying 83 files to /home/.../Desktop/bs/t1/build/web
Copied 22 empty directories to 11 empty directories under /home/prabhjeet/Desktop/bs/t1/build/web
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
In-place deployment at /home/..../Desktop/bs/t1/build/web
Deployment is in progress...
deploy?config=file%3A%2Ftmp%2Fcontext8772160632455666295.xml&path=/bstore
http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?config=file%3A%2Ftmp%2Fcontext8772160632455666295.xml&path=/bstore
/home/.../Desktop/bs/t1/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1032: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 36 seconds)
```

How to overcome this error?

Comment: checked this question ? [build-impl.xml:1031: The module has not been deployed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16400810/4290096)

Comment: @JAVY yes i tired that also, but error still continues.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue, in order to overcome it **it's necessary to install package "tomcat8-admin"**.

For debian/ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat8-admin
```

Configure the file /etc/tomcat8/tomcat-users.xml with the following roles and users:

```
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="YourUser" password="YourPassword" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui,manager-script"/>
```

Restart with:

```
/etc/init.d/tomcat8 restart
```

After this netbeans will prompt you for the user and password,and you should be good to go.

You can also check if it is working by trying to acces http://localhost:8080/manager/html, if it prompts you for password, tomcat8-admin is installed.